# bash: boolean in while loop

Tags: bash, scripting

This is probably a very simple / stupid question, but I am not understanding why I am not getting the expected value when I run this:

```
FOUND_FRONTDEV=false

echo "$PATHS" |
  while IFS= read -r line
do
    FOUND_FRONTDEV=true
    echo "$FOUND_FRONTDEV"
    break
done

echo "$FOUND_FRONTDEV"
```

It returns "true" then "false". It looks like the variable is local but it should not be. I am really confused why my second echo prints false. Does anyone know please?

Answer (score 4):

The while loop part is executed in a subshell. Hence the change you do to `FOUND_FRONTDEV` is not visible in the parent shell as the `FOUND_FRONTDEV` inside the while loop dies once the subshell exits.

Comment: Thanks! This was so stupid :) Thank you so much! I modified my loop to not pipe the echo :) Perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Because of your pipe, bash is executing the loop in a subshell, so it can't affect the environment outside it.  You can get around this by changing the `echo | while ...` to `while ... done <<<$PATHS`

Answer (score 4):

You have to change the while loop so that the `echo` part is run in a subshell and not the while loop itself. When the variable is changed in a subshell it is only changed there and not changed within the context of the parent shell.

So try:

```
FOUND_FRONTDEV=false

while IFS= read -r line ; do
    FOUND_FRONTDEV=true
    echo "$FOUND_FRONTDEV"
    break
done < <(echo "$PATHS")

echo "$FOUND_FRONTDEV"
```